# iterating through a List<String[]>

Tags: java, for-loop

Look at this code:

```
/*   Implementation to populate List<String[]> schedule  */

public List<String[]> getSchedBySIN(String sin) {
    List<String[]> listBySin = null;

    for (String[] temp : schedule) {
        if(temp[0].equals(sin)) listBySin.add(temp);
    }

    return listBySin;
}
```

`listBySin` on the line `...listBySin.add(temp);` is underlined with color yellow and Eclipse tells me this: *Null pointer access: The variable listBySin can only be null at this location*

Why is that? What I want to do is populate `listBySin` with string arrays from `schedule` if their first element is equal to `sin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a `List` object to the var.

```
List<String[]> listBySin = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to instantiate the List.

```
List<String[]> listBySin = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Answer (score 3):

initialize/assign your list  instead of

```
List<String[]> listBySin = null;
```

use following to initialize your list

```
List<String[]> listBySin = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first create the Object before you can call method on that. Something like

```
listBySin = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

before entering in the loop

Comment: Please note that the generic type is no longer required in a constructor as of Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

`You must initialize` `List` according. You can initialize with ArrayList or Vector or Stack or CopyOnWriteArrayList.

```
    List<String[]> str=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    List<String[]> str=new LinkedList<String[]>();
    List<String[]> str=new Stack<String[]>();
    List<String[]> str=new Vector<String[]>();
    List<String[]> str=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String[]>();
```

It all depends upon your need.